# How conceptually does this Scanner obtain data from the file? Does it involve the FileReader reading data into the Scanner's buffer?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
  String fileName;
  Scanner nameReader = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter a file name");
  fileName = nameReader.nextLine();           
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileReader(fileName));
```

For the code above, my professor told me that the FileReader esentially reads in data from the file to the Scanner's buffer. Then, we can access the data from the buffer using the next method, nextLine method, etc.
My question is, does the last line in the code provided above automatically and immediately fill scan's buffer with data read in from the file? I was confused by his statement, as I thought we would have to use some method for this to occur.

Comment: The pragmatic answer is "what difference does it make?".  Either the data are there, waiting for you to call nextSomething, or a read is issued if needed when you call nextSomething.  You can't tell the difference.  In practice, I'd expect the implementation to read from the file 'on demand' when it does not have the data to satisfy the request.  (It makes a difference for interactive use, of course).

Comment: The above is sort of a willful ignorance - you should program as if you only 'know' what the specification tells you is guaranteed to happen.  Intellectual curiosity is another matter entirely, and is to be encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

> For the code above, my professor told me that the FileReader esentially reads in data from the file to the Scanner's buffer.

That suggests a slight misunderstanding.  The `FileReader` has no particular knowledge of the `Scanner`, and cannot proactively do anything to or with it.  The agency goes in the other direction: the `Scanner` uses the `FileReader` to fill its own buffer.

> My question is, does the last line in the code provided above automatically and immediately fill scan's buffer with data read in from the file? I was confused by his statement, as I thought we would have to use some method for this to occur.

Probably not, but that's up to the `Scanner`.  Do remember that one of its constructors will run, and it is entirely reasonable to consider constructors a special kind of method.  In that sense, you *are* using a method of the `Scanner`, and it has an opportunity to eagerly fill the `Scanner`'s buffer.

In any case, there is no public method whose specific purpose is to fill the buffer.  Whether or not the constructor fills the buffer, the methods that scan data will (re)fill the buffer at need.

Comment: *"That suggests a slight misunderstanding ..."* - from the OP rather than their teacher.  I suspect that the OP has *misheard* the teacher.

Comment: That would be my guess, @StephenC, but I am not in a position to say, and it does not really matter as far as this answer is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

> For the code above, my professor told me that the `FileReader` essentially reads in data from the file to the `Scanner`'s buffer.

I think you misheard / misremembered your professor.  Or maybe, they "mispoke".

A more accurate characterization is that the (second) `Scanner` reads from the file by calling methods on the `FileReader`.  The `FileReader` has *no knowledge* of the `Scanner` that uses it ... yet alone that the `Scanner` has (or may have) an internal buffer of some kind.

It is important to note that we have two `Scanner` objects in the example.  They respectively getting information from two different sources.  One reads from standard input, and the the second one from a file.

> My question is, does the last line in the code provided above automatically and immediately fill scan's buffer with data read in from the file?

The answer is:

1. In practice, No.  Current implementations of `Scanner` will not perform the first read from the `FileReader` until your application actually calls a method on the `Scanner` object; e.g. a `next` or `hasNext` method.   The constructor won't do it.
2. In theory it is possible.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) is not crystal clear on this point.  It clearly says that a number of "scanning operations" may block waiting for data, which implies that they may read data from the underlying data source.  But it does NOT say anything about whether the constructors may or may not block.
3. I imagine that a vast amount of real world Java code has been written on the (IMO) *reasonable* assumption that a `Scanner` constructor will not try to preread data.  There is zero chance that `Scanner` will be changed to do this.

Comment: Wow this is very helpful. So basically, until we say for example, Scanner.next(), the FileReader will not perform the first read. So does this mean that esentially, when I call Scanner.next(), the fileReader will read in data, and pass it to the Scanner's buffer, and then Scanner.next() will return the data from its buffer?

Comment: Yes, that is what will happen the first time you call `next()` on the `Scanner`.  The second time, the scanner may not trigger reading from the file (or whatever) because there is more data data buffered from the first `read`.  However, it is mostly the `FileReader` that is doing the buffering.   (To really get an accurate picture, you need to look at the OpenJDK source code and/or study the javadocs very carefully.)

Answer (score -1):

Honestly, I don't know if I understand your question well
But if you want to use the scanner to read from a file, the following code reads and prints all the lines in the file in the desired path

```
  try {
        String path = "your file path";
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(path);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(fileReader);
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
            // stuff
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```